# need a reference (topological manifolds)

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology

hello, I need a book where i can find the proof for the classification of 1-dimensional topological manifolds.
(i already have Milnor's for the classification of 1-dimensional smooth manifolds)
thank you

Comment: What you need is the existence of a unique smooth structure (if it exists) on a 1-dim topological manifold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember well, Introduction to topological manifolds (Lee) proves the classification theorem for 1-dim manifolds.

Answer (score 4):

Fuks, D. B.; Rokhlin, V. A. Beginner's course in topology. Geometric chapters. Springer Series in Soviet Mathematics. Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York, 1984.

For dim 1 and dim 2 manifolds.